# left rotation operation in c++

Tags: c++, rotation

```
int main()
{
    int newposition, shiftSteps;
    int numbers[10], numberscopy[10];
    cin >> shiftSteps;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> numbers[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        numberscopy[i] = numbers[i];

    //------------------------------------

    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i - shiftSteps < 10 && i - shiftSteps >= 0)
            newposition = i - shiftSteps;
        else
            newposition = i - shiftSteps + 10;
        numbers[newposition] = numberscopy[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}
```

I want to rotate 10 numbers to left and **"shiftSteps"** is number of moves to the left. but I have a problem, the code I wrote so far for some numbers it works properly like `{0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} and shiftSteps = 3` output is `3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2`.
but if inputs are `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and `shiftSteps = 15`, the output is `5 6 7 8 9 5 6 7 8 9`  and 0 Disappears, True answer for shiftSteps = 15 is `5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4`.

Comment: In your example `shiftSteps` is uninitializated.

Comment: [Why using "namespace std;" is considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `std::rotate` will do what you want.

Comment: There is [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: @GaryNLOL: There is no `using namespace std;` in OP code. It might be `using std::cin;` :)

Comment: @Jarod42 `using std::cin;` in the global namespace isn't exactly ideal either. But at least it's not nearly as bad as `using namespace std;`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Where is your code that reads `shiftSteps `? It appears that you have some indexing errors. I suggest adding a line `shiftSteps = shiftSteps % 10;` after you read that number to fix indexing errors.

Comment: You could look at ready implementations like the one @Jarod42 pointed out and try to make use of that ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/T66vha)). Analyze what it's doing and perhaps you'll get some good ideas for your own implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `newposition = i - shiftSteps + 10;` results in a negative value for `shiftSteps == 15` and `i < 5`. This results in an out-of-bounds access.

You need to ensure that the rotation amount is below the number of elements of the array, which can be achieved with a modulus operator.

```
    shiftSteps = shiftSteps % 10;

    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        newposition = i - shiftSteps;
        if (newposition < 0)
            newposition += 10;
        numbers[newposition] = numberscopy[i];
    }
```

This will work for non-negative values of `shiftSteps`. If you also need to handle negatives, you should adjust the condition in the loop accordingly.

PS: Also, note that in your code `shiftSteps` is left uninitialized.

PPS: You could also use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) algorithm.